# Flash in WebView not working on Android 3.2

Tags: android, flash, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am having a problem that only happens on my Motorola Xoom which I have updated to 3.2 through OTA. I have a simple application that uses a WebView to load a small html that has flash content in it. Here is the code snippet.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

I know it is correct because it can run fine on my Samsung Galaxy S running Android 2.2. Anybody else seen this problem? Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Many thanks and I am really stuck here.

Comment: Just did some more experiments. Same problem when I tried to load the swf file directly instead of a html file - works fine on 2.2 but nothing shows up on 3.2.

Comment: I've been getting reports from users with 3.2 (on other devices) running into the same issue with flash.

Comment: Thanks, Pete. Any suggestions on any possible workarounds?

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to [build your application with the latest android Api](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html#Upgrading) (13), and activate hardware acceleration (same link, just a little below) on your activity that need to display flash.

Comment: Nitro, Just got some time to try it out and it seems working now. Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1

Comment: FYI: Works on Android 4 (ICS)