# WebView won't play embedded flash video

Tags: android, flash, video, android-webview

I am testing on a Xoom device, running OS 3.2. The project is built (in Eclipse) using the 3.1 library.

I have the latest version of flash installed, and embedded flash plays fine in my tablet's browser.

If I create an activity like this:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browserView);
browser .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser .getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
browser .loadUrl("http://m.kongregate.com/games/Jiggmin/the-game-of-disorientation-mobile");
```

Then I hear the sound playing for the flash, but it shows up as a white box.

Similarly, any other page with embedded flash has the same problem. I've also tried making a string containing static HTML content, and loading that into the browser... but it has the same problem.

I've read every solution I could find online, from setting the view to invisible until the onPageFinish event is called, to extending the WebView class, and paining over it. I've tried reflection, to call hidden properties on the WebView's settings for enabling flash, etc. Nothing works.

Please help!

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: See this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102446/flash-in-webview-not-working-on-android-3-2/7104036#7104036) :

> Try to build your application with the latest android Api ( http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/optimizing-for-3.0.html#Upgrading ),
>   and activate hardware acceleration (same link, just a little below) on
>   your activity that need to display flash.

Comment: I had tried adding the hardware acceleration property in the manifest, but I didn't try building with the latest Api (3.2). I'll give that a shot tonight. I'm not convinced it will work, but we'll see! Thanks.

Comment: I'm eating my words, changing the SDK from 3.1 to 3.2 worked! Thanks! However... if I want to release the app in the marketplace and have it work for 3.2 devices?

Comment: Just put the minSdk in the manifest to allow the usage of your usage for older version of Android.

Comment: Was the problem that I was using a newer Android OS (3.2) but compiling for an older one (3.1), so Flash was messing up? Would that mean my app can support 3.1 or 3.2, but not both?

Comment: No, there is seems that there is a bug with 3.2 and flash. You app will support 3.1 and 3.2, if you set the minSdk to api 12(3.1), but compile it with 3.2, it will work on both.