# Play SWF file in webViewClient on ICS?

Tags: android, flash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I tried to open an SWF file in webViewClient and it works on Android 2.1 and 2.3.3.
But when I try to play the same SWF file on 4.0.4, it causes an error and a green screen appears in the videoPlayer page.

```
oWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvhPlayer);
oWebView.setWebViewClient(new KhWebClient());
oWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
oWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
oWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
oWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

String html = " <object classid=\"clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" id=\"vPlayer\" align=\"middle\">"
            + " <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://mysite.com/sites/all/modules/player/player.swf?id=0CYj9tI0hpQ"
            + "\" />"
            + "  <param name=\"quality\" value=\"high\" />"
            + " <param name=\"bgcolor\" value=\"#000000\" />"
            + " <param name=\"play\" value=\"true\" />"
            + " <param name=\"loop\" value=\"true\" />"
            + " <param name=\"wmode\" value=\"window\" />"
            + " <param name=\"scale\" value=\"showall\" />"
            + " <param name=\"menu\" value=\"true\" />"
            + " <param name=\"devicefont\" value=\"false\" />"
            + " </object>";

oWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("null", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: In case you missed the news, Adobe plans to drop support for Flash on Android. I'd recommend finding an alternative to Flash if you want this change to continue to work on JellyBean and later releases of Android.

Please see (http://lifehacker.com/5922466/remains-of-the-day-adobe-dropping-flash-from-android) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1), i used to load the swf file instead of loading a html.

its work like a charm.

1. Add to AndroidManifest.xml

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

2.

```
oWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvhPlayer);
oWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
oWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
oWebView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com/sites/all/modules/player/player.swf?id=0CYj9tI0hpQ");
```

Comment: hardwareAccelerated="true" was added from Android 3.0. I want to play it on Android 2.3. Is there any work around ?

Comment: try the above solution without hardwareAccelerated="true"

Answer (score -1):

I found a bug(one of them) in android 4.0 with hardware acceleration in `WebViewClient`. By default they set it to true, so try setting it to false in your manifest and tell me what happen.

*If this fix the problem please consider moving to Iphone...

Comment: Nothing change android:hardwareAccelerated="false"