# How To Embed YouTube Video on Android using Phonegap

Tags: android, video, cordova, youtube, embed

I've been trying to embed YouTube videos inside my phonegap Android app using the new YouTube iframe API.
The embed itself working and a YouTube window pops in with the preview picture and the play button in the center. 
The problem is when I click the button to start streaming the video the embed doesn't play the video - just loads the preview picture in and does nothing.
The code used is below if it helps.

```
 & lt;iframe title="YouTube video player"
class="YouTube-player" type="text/HTML" width="320" height="194"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxx" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I read from any article that if using iPhone just change setting on phonegap.plist this

```
MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: NO
AllowInlineMediaPlayback: YES
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView: YES
ExternalHosts
          *.youtube.com
          *.ytimg.com
```

how about in android...?

Answer (score 0):

Please used this [plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer) to play youtube video in android-phonegap application.
Please follow steps given in [this](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html) blog.

After successful integration of plugin used following code to play youtube video:

```
window.plugins.videoPlayer.play("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E0UV5i5jY50");
```

Comment: That will fire an intent to youtube app, it does not embed the video in the app itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case (Phonegap 2.9 + Android 4.2) the problem was minSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
```

When I tried to set it lower than '14' it ceased to display video stream like in your case (the preview was still ok)

Update:

.. but if you add enable hardware acceleration in AndroidManifest.xml, everything works fine even with lower versions of Android

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Everything is explained in details in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1/5439573#5439573)

Answer (score 0):

Check if in console you have any error like "access denied" when loading the video, if that's the case: edit your config.xml file and add

```
<access origin="http://youtube.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="http://ytimg.com" subdomains="true"/>
```