# Android - Show aparat videos in the application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Aparat is an online video service like youtube, I want to know how can I show one of the videos in my application ? For example I want to show this [video](http://www.aparat.com/v/d8wFA), but not the whole page, just the video .
How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I do this job! loading aparat videos in my android app. just follow below steps:
First, you need this java class:

```
public class WebVideoView {

private String url;
private Context context;
private WebView webview;
private static final String HTML_TEMPLATE = "webvideo.html";

public CWebVideoView(Context context, WebView webview) {
    this.webview = webview;
    this.context = context;
    webview.setBackgroundColor(0);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

public void load(String url){
    this.url = url;
    String data = readFromfile(HTML_TEMPLATE, context);
    data = data.replace("%1", url);
    webview.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");
}

public String readFromfile(String fileName, Context context) {
    StringBuilder returnString = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream fIn = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
        fIn = context.getResources().getAssets().open(fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        input = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            returnString.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (isr != null)
                isr.close();
            if (fIn != null)
                fIn.close();
            if (input != null)
                input.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.getMessage();
        }
    }
    return returnString.toString();
}

public void reload() {
    if (url!=null){
        load(url);
    }
}
```

}

Second, in assets folder create WebVideo.html file and paste the following codes in it:

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            iframe   { border: 0; position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; bgcolor="#000000"; }
            body     { margin: 0; bgcolor="#000000"; }
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="%1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in your layout that you want to show the video add this view:

```css
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/video"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Finally, in your activity define your view like below codes and replace the url that you want to show in your activity with the url in load method(last line):

```
    WebView videoView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.video);
    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    WebVideoView webVideoView = new CWebVideoView(this, videoView);
    webVideoView.load("url");
```

Enjoy your videos :)

there is a point that in url, you should insert iframe code that it is available in aparat website for each video below it. ;)

Comment: Thank you, I see your answer after a year. LOL. BTW, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that service but from the link you provided I was able to get the following embed html:

```
<iframe src="http://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/d8wFA/vt/frame" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" height="360" width="640" ></iframe>
```

So one way to do it that I was able to get working in a quick standalone app is to just put that into a webview:

```
String videoEmbedHtml = "<iframe src=\"http://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/d8wFA/vt/frame\" allowFullScreen=\"true\" webkitallowfullscreen=\"true\" mozallowfullscreen=\"true\" height=\"360\" width=\"640\" ></iframe>";
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadData(videoEmbedHtml, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Alternatively you could find out if these guys have an Android SDK.

Comment: Thank you , Actually because of some restrictions in my country i can not use YouTube instead, I'll test this and tell the result .

Comment: I don't know why but the webview just play the audio, Not the video ! what's the problem ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what the exact issue will be there, have you tried setting `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` on your application in the manifest? I found an old question on here which might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383364/flash-video-not-displaying-in-webview-for-android-3-0-1

Comment: I've did that and all similar solutions in other topics but unfortunately no changes happened . Is there any other way to show an online video in my application ? thanks in advance .

Comment: Do you have any idea ?